# ruby - start a thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am new to ruby and trying to work around threads

Let's say I have a method which I want to run every **x seconds** as follows

```
def say_hello
    puts 'hello world'
end
```

I am trying to run it as follows

```
Thread.new do
    while true do
        say_hello
        sleep(5)
    end
end
```

But when I run the script, nothing is displayed on the console. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I think your program exits suddenly after the Thread has started. If you put something like sleep(100) after the thread you will find the output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main thread is exiting before your thread can run. Use the join method to make the current thread wait for the `say_hello` thread to finish executing (though it never will).

```
t = Thread.new do
    while true do
        say_hello
        sleep(5)
    end
end

t.join
```

Answer (score 5):

You are creating the Thread object, but you are not waiting for it to finish its execution, try with:

```
Thread.new do
    while true do
        say_hello
        sleep(5)
    end
end.join
```

Comment: That is not entirely correct. The thread will also execute without the `join`, but it will be exited when the main process exits.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
t1 = Thread.new do
    while true do
        say_hello
        sleep(5)
    end
end

t1.join
```

Comment: I downvoted this because when I put this in a script and ran it, the script immediately finished.  It did not print anything.

Comment: sorry I forgot the join method

Comment: and if you put this in a separate .rb file and run it without .join, it won't run since the main loop finishes first. However, if you put call this in ruby console irb, it will still run without .join

Comment: @SeWonJang: Fair enough.:)

Comment: @SeWonJang: it will run, yes, but it won't print anything.

Comment: @Davidann It does print what is expected

Comment: @SeWonJang: Dah, yuo're right.  I forgot about the `t1.join`:)

Comment: @Davidann but when I run it on irb console, it runs as expected even without t1.join